# Button_Click without PostBack

Tags: asp.net, postback

In my below code when is button clicked the textbox value is being added to the database and the same is displayed in the DataBinder are reloading the page. Well, just like chat script I need whole process to be done without postback. So, how to pass the value from textbox to DataBinder without reloading the page. i.e. How to perform Button Click such that it do not postback.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            string MyConString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" + "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=repeater;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=****;" + "OPTION=3";
            OdbcConnection MyConnection = new OdbcConnection(MyConString);
            try
            {
                MyConnection.Open();
                OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("Select message from table1", MyConnection);
                OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                ArrayList values = new ArrayList();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    if (!IsPostBack)
                    {
                    string ep = dr[0].ToString();
                    values.Add(new PositionData(ep));
                    Shout_Box.DataSource = values;
                    Shout_Box.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
            string MyConString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" + "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=repeater;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=*****;" + "OPTION=3";
            OdbcConnection MyConnection = new OdbcConnection(MyConString);
            OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO table1(message)VALUES(?)", MyConnection);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = TextBox1.Text;
            MyConnection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MyConnection.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick and dirty way would be to use an Update Panel.  It would appear to your end-users to occur without a postback and you would only need to make minor changes to your page.

More information: [Introduction to the UpdatePanel control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx) (MSDN)

Comment: Well, but even if I use update panel. I should make a button click after entering text is textbox right?

Comment: Correct.  In actuality, an Update Panel performs a postback but it uses a bit of trickery to appear as if it were asynchronous.  This means that you can code exactly as if you were performing a full postback and the the .net framework handles the rest for you.  Just place your button inside of the UpdatePanel and you'll be done.  The whole process should take you less than 5 minutes.

Comment: Alison everything is working fine. But when I place `TextBox` inside `</ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>` even `TextBox` too is triggering due to timer and I am unable to add any text. If I place `TextBox` outside I am unable to clear its value. I posted separate question please read it here http://stackoverflow.com/q/7355210/903455

Answer (score 1):

Shortly: JavaScript, JQuery, AJAX

you have to use one of them, to succeed that; because any button on asp.net page if it runs on server, will already send postBack.

UpdatePanel is an AJAX component, you can use it, so that your button does not send postBack (or you are not effected)

Comment: Well, but even if I use update panel. I should make a button click after entering text is textbox right?